# Determine if a given lat-lon belong to a polygon

Tags: r, point-in-polygon

Assume I have a data file called `zone` with `1994` strings of `2D` coordinators denoting coordinates of vertices of polygons like the following (the very first number on the RHS of each line denotes the `zone`)

`c1 <- "1", "1 21, 31 50, 45 65, 75 80"`

`c2 <- "2", "3 20, 5 15, 2 26, 70 -85, 40 50, 60 80"`

.....

`c1993 <- "1993", "3 2, 2 -5, 0 60, 7 -58, -12 23, 56 611, 85 152"`

`c1994 <- "1994", "30 200, 50 -15, 20 260, 700 -850, -1 2, 5 6, 8 15"`

Now I want to manipulate these strings in such a way that given a random pair of `lat-lon` (let's say `12` and `20`), I could compare to see if it falls into first polygon, second polygon, 3rd polygon,.... or 1994th polygon. The **brute-force** solution is: compare the `x-coordinate` (`= 12`) to all the `4` `x`-coordinates and `y-coordinate`(`= 20) to all the`4y`-coordinates in`c1`and`c2`, respectively. The conclusion would be whether there is a valid **sandwich** inequality for each given coordinate`x`and`y`.

For example, by using the solution process as above, the point `(12,20)` will be in c1 but not c2.

**My question:** How could I achieve this goal in R?

**My attempt:** Thanks to  Stéphane Laurent's help, I was able to generate all the matrices, each with certain sizes, that store the `lat-lon` pairs of all the vertices of each polygon with the following code:

```
 zone <- read_delim("[directory path to zone.csv file]", delim = ",", col_names = TRUE)
for(i in 1:nrow(zone)){
  zone$geo[i] = substr(zone$geo[i],10,135)
}
zone <- zone[complete.cases(zone),]

 Numextract <- function(string){
    unlist(regmatches(string, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", string)))
 }

for(i in 1:nrow(zone)){
        poly1 <- matrix(as.numeric(Numextract(zone$geo[i])),i, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
        poly2 <- cbind(poly1, c(i))
}
```

However, as you might see, I need to find a way to **index** every matrices corresponding to each zone that were generated during the `for()` loop. The reason is because afterwards, I can use another `for()` loop to determine which zone a point belongs to!! But I have not been able to figure this out, so can anyone please help me with a detailed code?

**Actual dataset**
 [Zone and polygons dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KDx44p_eateXieL792QIds_NiqbW9P9h)

[Lat-Lon pairs dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uNulfB6B8FJIQESbNdA8ztf3fQ5DYEkh)

Comment: Probably this question belongs to `gis.stackexchange`.

Comment: Do you have any control on how you define `c1` and `c2`? Will they always be a string in the form `lat lon, lat lon, lat lon, ...`, or are you free to define them however you want?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36683825/1100107

Comment: @SymbolixAU: yes, all of them are in that format, as you pointed out. There are the entire `1614` string in that format. But of course, we can change it using codes in R, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, define your polygons as matrices, each row representing a vertex:

```
poly1 <- rbind(c(1,21), c(31,50), c(45,65), c(75,80))
poly2 <- rbind(c(3,20), c(5,15), c(2,26), c(70,-85))
```

Define the point to be tested:

```
point <- c(12,20)
```

Now, use the `pip2d` function of the `ptinpoly` package:

```
> library(ptinpoly)
> pip2d(poly1, rbind(point))
[1] -1
> pip2d(poly2, rbind(point))
[1] 1
```

That means (see `?pip2d`) that the point is outside `poly1` and inside `poly2`.

Note the `rbind(point)` in `pip2d`. We use `rbind` because we can more generally run the test for several points in a same polygon.

If you need help to convert

```
c1 <- "1 21, 31 50, 45 65, 75 80"
```

to

```
poly1 <- rbind(c(1,21), c(31,50), c(45,65), c(75,80))
```

then maybe you should open another question.

## Edit

Ok, do not open another question. You can proceed as follows.

```
c1 <- "1 21, 31 50, 45 65, 75 80"

Numextract <- function(string){
  unlist(regmatches(string, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", string)))
}

poly1 <- matrix(as.numeric(Numextract(c1)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Which gives:

```
> poly1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   21
[2,]   31   50
[3,]   45   65
[4,]   75   80
```

## 2nd Edit

For your second problem, your data are too big. The only solution I can see is to split the data into smaller pieces.

But first of all, it seems that the `pip2d` function also causes the R session to crash. So use another function: `pnt.in.poly` from the package `SDMTools`.

Here is a small modification of this function, making it faster by removing useless outputs:

```
library(SDMTools)
pnt.in.poly2 <- function(pnts, poly.pnts){
  if (poly.pnts[1, 1] == poly.pnts[nrow(poly.pnts), 1] && 
      poly.pnts[1, 2] == poly.pnts[nrow(poly.pnts), 2]){ 
    poly.pnts = poly.pnts[-1, ]
  }
  out = .Call("pip", pnts[, 1], pnts[, 2], nrow(pnts), poly.pnts[,1], poly.pnts[, 2], nrow(poly.pnts), PACKAGE = "SDMTools")
  return(out)
}
```

Now, as said before, split `lat_lon` in smaller pieces, 1 million length each, (except the last one, smaller):

```
lat_lon_list <- vector("list", 70)
for(i in 1:69){
  lat_lon_list[[i]] = lat_lon[(1+(i-1)*1e6):(i*1e6),]
}
lat_lon_list[[70]] <- lat_lon[69000001:nrow(lat_lon),]
```

Now, run this code:

```
library(data.table)
for(i in 1:70){
  DT <- data.table(V1 = pnt.in.poly2(lat_lon_list[[i]], polys[[1]]))
  for(j in 2:length(polys)){
    DT[, (sprintf("V%d",j)):=pnt.in.poly2(lat_lon_list[[i]], polys[[j]])]
  }
  fwrite(DT, sprintf("results%02d.csv", i))
  rm(DT)
}
```

If it works, it should generate 70 csv files, `result01.csv`, ..., `result70.csv`, each of size `1000000x1944` (except the last one, smaller), then it's possible to open them in Excel.

## 3rd edit

I've tried the code and I've got an error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.6 Mb`.

We need a finer splitting:

```
lat_lon_list <- vector("list", 2*69+1)
for(i in 1:(2*69)){
  lat_lon_list[[i]] = lat_lon[(1+(i-1)*1e6/2):(i*1e6/2),]
}
lat_lon_list[[2*69+1]] <- lat_lon[69000001:nrow(lat_lon),]

for(i in 1:(2*69+1)){
  DT <- data.table(V1 = pnt.in.poly2(lat_lon_list[[i]], polys[[1]]))
  for(j in 2:length(polys)){
    DT[, (sprintf("V%d",j)):=pnt.in.poly2(lat_lon_list[[i]], polys[[j]])]
  }
  fwrite(DT, sprintf("results%02d.csv", i))
  rm(DT)
}
```

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: can you please help me deal with the scaling issue? I tried looping through **1994** polygon zones (rather than looping over **69.3M** pairs of `lat-lon`), but R still crashes.

Comment: @user177196 I tried during a couple of hours. This is not possible. This requires too big memory. The only solution I see is to split `lat_lon` into smaller pieces and saving the results in one file for each piece.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: What a code!! Unfortunately, I tried running through it, but encountered the error message: `"Error in pnts[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions."` The line that caused the error is in `" out = .Call("pip", pnts[, 1], pnts[, 2], nrow(pnts), poly.pnts[,1], poly.pnts[, 2], nrow(poly.pnts), PACKAGE = "SDMTools")."` ---> What is the intention of this output line though?

Comment: @user177196 Hmm weird. I tested only quickly. I will run the code now to see what happens.

Comment: Ah I see my error... wait. The error is in the splitting.

Comment: @user177196 See my update. The error was in `lat_lon_list`.

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot to click on "Save edit" ^^ That's done now.

Comment: @user177196 This will take a while if it works. After 5 minutes, the first csv file is not written yet. And there are 70 csv files to write.

Comment: @user177196 I've had a crash. `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.6 Mb`. The loop ran until `j=1422`. Does it work for you ? Otherwise we need a finer splitting.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I let my computer run for nearly 30 mins with the original splitting, and it still has not stopped running. A red sign with letter "STOP" still appears in the console. Does your finer splitting work? I am wondering if using `dplyr::groupby()` affter this, to obtain the sum of the other `count` element in the original dataset, if they are in the same `zone`, is possible.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I am getting this message with your unmodified code: `Written 38.8% of 1000000 rows in 61 secs using 1 thread. anyBufferGrown=no; maxBuffUsed=49%. Finished in 96 secs.` Did you ever get it when you run it?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: how long did it take you to get to the `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.6 Mb` place? My computer is running for 2 hours, and it only outputs `8` .csv files

Comment: @user177196 About 10 minutes, this was the first file. The finer splitting works but the csv files are ~2Gb and I can't open them in Excel because they are too big. Can you open them ?

Comment: I am still running with the original splitting. I think I can only get **all** the results out in the next 2 hours at the earliest. Horrible;p But the file that is as big can only be opened by either text-reader software (like textEditor, Sublime, etc?) or R directly? 
On the side note: I plan to use `[dataset] %>% group_by(zone) %>%summarize (sum=sum(ON))` where `ON` is a column in original dataset (must be added to each of these 70 csv files). Do you think this could process these `.csv` files??

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: only up to 13th .csv file. What kind of *super* computer are you using to get all the files?? I am using Macbook Air with 8GB RAM.

Comment: My R just said aborted now. It wasted 3 hours;p

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I got this error `Error in if (poly.pnts[1, 1] == poly.pnts[nrow(poly.pnts), 1] && poly.pnts[1,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. But my `polys` are fulfilled...

Comment: @user177196 This error is weird, I don't understand. I have checked that all the polygons are correct. You can add a `print(i)` and a `print(j)` in the loops to check the index for which the error occurs. In this way you can restart the loop from this index so that you don't waste time (the files are saved). I never said I got all the files. I only got the first three ones and I aborted. But I have no text editor able to open these big files. Maybe https://kothar.net/csview could open them.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I was able to fix that. Unfortunately, I encountered the `memory space not enough` issue when the code outputs up to `37th` `.csv` files. Now I have to clean up the disk in Mac Air before I re-run everything...

Comment: @user177196 Don't re-run everything. Save the 37 files to an external hard drive and re-run the loop from `i=38`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I am so sorry for letting you down, but I finally got it using `left_join()` with an additional dataset:((

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: could you please help me with my code to solve another puzzle here, as I don't understand why I get that error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950683/constructing-matrix-based-on-row-entries-of-data-frame