# Faster way of evaluating points inside a list of polygons in R

Tags: r, r-sp, point-in-polygon

I have two data sets, one with over 13 million rectangle polygons (set of 4 lat lng points) and another with 10 thousand points referring to prices in that location.

```
> polygons
     id                                 pol_lat                                 pol_lng
 1: 148 -4.250236,-4.250236,-4.254640,-4.254640 -49.94628,-49.94494,-49.94494,-49.94628
 2: 149 -4.254640,-4.254640,-5.361601,-5.361601 -49.94494,-49.07906,-49.07906,-49.94494
 3: 150 -5.361601,-5.361601,-5.212208,-5.212208 -49.07906,-49.04469,-49.04469,-49.07906
 4: 151 -5.212208,-5.212208,-5.002878,-5.002878 -49.04469,-48.48664,-48.48664,-49.04469
 5: 152 -5.002878,-5.002878,-5.080018,-5.080018 -48.48664,-48.43699,-48.43699,-48.48664
 6: 153 -5.080018,-5.080018,-5.079819,-5.079819 -48.43699,-48.42480,-48.42480,-48.43699
 7: 154 -5.079819,-5.079819,-5.155606,-5.155606 -48.42480,-47.53891,-47.53891,-48.42480
 8: 155 -5.155606,-5.155606,-4.954156,-4.954156 -47.53891,-47.50354,-47.50354,-47.53891
 9: 156 -4.954156,-4.954156,-3.675864,-3.675864 -47.50354,-45.39022,-45.39022,-47.50354
10: 157 -3.675864,-3.675864,-3.706356,-3.706356 -45.39022,-45.30724,-45.30724,-45.39022
11: 158 -3.706356,-3.706356,-3.705801,-3.705801 -45.30724,-45.30722,-45.30722,-45.30724
> points
    longitude  latitude  price
 1: -47.50308 -4.953936 3.0616
 2: -47.50308 -4.953936 3.2070
 3: -47.50308 -4.953936 3.0630
 4: -47.50308 -4.953936 3.0603
 5: -47.50308 -4.953936 3.0460
 6: -47.50308 -4.953936 2.9900
 7: -49.07035 -5.283658 3.3130
 8: -49.08054 -5.347284 3.3900
 9: -49.08054 -5.347284 3.3620
10: -49.21726 -5.338270 3.3900
11: -49.08050 -5.347255 3.4000
12: -49.08042 -5.347248 3.3220
13: -49.08190 -5.359508 3.3130
14: -49.08046 -5.347277 3.3560
```

I want to generate a mean price among all points that fit inside each polygon, for each polygon.

Right now I am using `sp::point.in.polygon` to get indices to all points that fit inside a given polygon, and then get its mean price

```
w <- lapply(1:nrow(polygons),
            function(tt) {
              ind <- point.in.polygon(points$latitude, points$longitude,
                                      polygons$pol_lat[[tt]], polygons$pol_lng[[tt]]) > 0
              med <- mean(points$price[ind])
              return(med)
            }
)
> unlist(w)
 [1]      NaN 3.361857 3.313000      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN 3.071317      NaN      NaN
```

However, this is, obviously, slow. Any ideas on how to do it faster, maybe using `data.table` or `dplyr` (or any other means)?

Data follows

```
> dput(polygons)
structure(list(id = 148:158, pol_lat = list(c(-4.2502356, -4.2502356, 
-4.2546403, -4.2546403), c(-4.2546403, -4.2546403, -5.3616014, 
-5.3616014), c(-5.3616014, -5.3616014, -5.2122078, -5.2122078
), c(-5.2122078, -5.2122078, -5.0028781, -5.0028781), c(-5.0028781, 
-5.0028781, -5.0800181, -5.0800181), c(-5.0800181, -5.0800181, 
-5.0798186, -5.0798186), c(-5.0798186, -5.0798186, -5.1556063, 
-5.1556063), c(-5.1556063, -5.1556063, -4.9541564, -4.9541564
), c(-4.9541564, -4.9541564, -3.6758637, -3.6758637), c(-3.6758637, 
-3.6758637, -3.706356, -3.706356), c(-3.706356, -3.706356, -3.7058011, 
-3.7058011)), pol_lng = list(c(-49.9462826, -49.9449427, -49.9449427, 
-49.9462826), c(-49.9449427, -49.0790599, -49.0790599, -49.9449427
), c(-49.0790599, -49.0446868, -49.0446868, -49.0790599), c(-49.0446868, 
-48.4866355, -48.4866355, -49.0446868), c(-48.4866355, -48.436988, 
-48.436988, -48.4866355), c(-48.436988, -48.4247989, -48.4247989, 
-48.436988), c(-48.4247989, -47.5389072, -47.5389072, -48.4247989
), c(-47.5389072, -47.5035404, -47.5035404, -47.5389072), c(-47.5035404, 
-45.3902168, -45.3902168, -47.5035404), c(-45.3902168, -45.3072392, 
-45.3072392, -45.3902168), c(-45.3072392, -45.3072216, -45.3072216, 
-45.3072392))), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000025e1ef0>)
> dput(points)
structure(list(longitude = c(-47.5030772, -47.5030772, -47.5030772, 
-47.5030772, -47.5030772, -47.5030772, -49.0703469, -49.0805422, 
-49.0805422, -49.217259, -49.0804978, -49.0804181, -49.0818997, 
-49.0804625), latitude = c(-4.9539357, -4.9539357, -4.9539357, 
-4.9539357, -4.9539357, -4.9539357, -5.283658, -5.3472839, -5.3472839, 
-5.3382696, -5.3472551, -5.347248, -5.3595084, -5.3472768), price = c(3.0616, 
3.207, 3.063, 3.0603, 3.046, 2.99, 3.313, 3.39, 3.362, 3.39, 
3.4, 3.322, 3.313, 3.356)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000025e1ef0>)
```

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683825/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-in-a-polygon-effectively-using-r-for-large-data-set/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828692/determine-if-a-given-lat-lon-belong-to-a-polygon/

Comment: I have been to the second link, but `ptinpoly` does not give much of a speed boost. Will see if the answers in the first link helps. Thanks

Comment: not an expert on spatial stats, but your lapply is iterating over all polygons, which might be inefficient if the number of points is much smaller than the number of polygons (as it apparently is in your case). have you tried iterating over points instead, and then seeing if it belongs to a polygon? the nice thing about this approach is that, if the polygons are a partition, then once you've found the polygon to which a point belongs, you can stop looking elsewhere and move on to the next point.

Comment: Kinda feeling dumb right now, for not thinking about it. Thanks @mbiron

Comment: No problem man. In fact, you could maybe do better. For each point, instead of checking each polygon at random (which is already a gain because on average you will only check half of the polygons), you could first calculate the distances from the point to the centroids of all the polygons (this can be done fast), and then evaluate the polygons in ascending order of distance. This way, you should hopefully evaluate just a handful of polygons until you find the one with the point inside.

Comment: Also, instead of sorting the entire vector of distances of length 13 million, you could use the `partial` argument of function `sort` to get the closest 10 or 100 polygons. It would be reaally weird if the point didn't belong to any of the closest 100 elements, and this is probably imposible in the usual spatial stats setup.

Comment: My polygons can have overlapping regions. I already check only the closest polygons to each point. Inverting the loop, i.e., iterating over points instead, did the trick

Comment: Mmm...don't know if i am following, here. Seems that unless you can make some assumption regarding polygons size, checking only the closest polys can lead to errors. Nothing in theory prevents a point which is far from the centroid of a certain poly from still being inside it, if the polygon is large.

Comment: they are quite small. My polygons are rectangles over Google Maps directions turning points over the entire continent of South America, so pretty hard to miss a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your "polygons" are always rectangles** as in the example,  a possibility is to use a QuadTree spatial index, as implemented in package `SearchTrees`, to improve the speed of identification of which points fall in each polygon.

It could give you a rather big speed boost thanks to the lower number of "comparisons" to be done granted by the spatial indexing, the larger the greater the number of **points** in your dataset.

For example:

```
library(SearchTrees)
library(magrittr)

# Create a "beefier" test dataset based on your data: 14000 pts 
# over 45000 polygons

for (i in 1:10) points   <- rbind(points, points + runif(length(points)))
for (i in 1:12) polygons <- rbind(polygons, polygons)


# Compute limits of the polygons
min_xs <- lapply(polygons$pol_lng , min) %>% unlist()
max_xs <- lapply(polygons$pol_lng , max) %>% unlist()
min_ys <- lapply(polygons$pol_lat , min) %>% unlist()
max_ys <- lapply(polygons$pol_lat, max) %>% unlist()
xlims <- cbind(min_xs, max_xs)
ylims <- cbind(min_ys, max_ys)

# Create the quadtree
tree = SearchTrees::createTree(cbind(points[1],points[2]))

#☻ extract averages, looping over polygons ----
t1 <- Sys.time()
w <- lapply(1:nrow(polygons), 
            function(tt) {
              ind <- SearchTrees::rectLookup(
                tree, 
                xlims = xlims[tt,],
                ylims = ylims[tt,]))
              mean(points$price[ind])

              })
Sys.time() - t1
```

> Time difference of 2.945789 secs

```
w1 <- unlist(w)
```

On my old laptop, this "naive" implementation is more than 10 times faster than your original approach on the test data:

```
t1 <- Sys.time()
w <- lapply(1:nrow(polygons),
            function(tt) {
              ind <- sp::point.in.polygon(points$latitude, points$longitude,
                                      polygons$pol_lat[[tt]], polygons$pol_lng[[tt]]) > 0
              med <- mean(points$price[ind])
              return(med)
            }
)
Sys.time() - t1
w2 <- unlist(w)
```

> Time difference of 40.36493 secs

, with the same results:

```
> all.equal(w1, w2)
[1] TRUE
```

The overall speed improvement will depend on how your points are "clustered" over the spatial extent, and with respect to the polygons.

Consider that you could exploit this approach also if your polygons are not rectangular, by first extracting the points included in the bbox of each polygon, and later finding the ones "inside" the polygon with a more standard approach.

Also consider that the task is embarassingly parallel, so that you could easily improve performance by using a `foreach` or `parlapply` approach over the polygons.

HTH!

Comment: this helped a lot. Weird thing is that it was 4x faster, not 10x. Still, quite an improvement