# How to check if a point is inside a square using bivrp::is_point_inside

Tags: r, polygon, point, square

I am trying `bivrp::is_point_inside` to check if a point is inside a square, but no matter what I try, I always get FALSE, even in the most obvious cases... What am I doing wrong??

My code:

```
polyg=data.frame(c(15, 15, 0, 0), c(15, 0, 0, 15))
point=c(5,5)
bivrp::is_point_inside(point, polyg)
```

I think we would all agree that a point at `5,5` would be inside a square with coordinates `15,15`, `15,0`, `0,0`, `0,15`, however:

```
> bivrp::is_point_inside(point, polyg)
[1] FALSE
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Note I prioritise the use of `bivrp::is_point_inside`; I have some older code where I used it and never had any problem, if it doesn't work properly anymore, I would have to revise the older code.

**EDIT**

This function clearly does not work... Can someone suggest a function that does the same (check if a point is inside a polygon) but works? I will have to revise my old code using it...

Comment: By common convention, polygons are defined by tracing the points anti-clockwise. Yours is defined clockwise. This might cause issues. That being said, reversing the order of the points to be in anti-clockwise order does not change the result. And even much simpler examples fail, e.g. `is_point_inside(c(1, 1), data.frame(c(0, 2, 2, 0), c(0, 0, 2, 2)))`.

Comment: this test just gave me TRUE: `bivrp::is_point_inside(c(2, 1), data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(1, 0, 1, 3)))`... I'm really at a loss here

Comment: @DaniCee Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75322645/3460670) as one option.

Answer (score 1):

Good news. I just tested your example with `secr` and it seems to work just fine.

Here's the sample code:

```
library(secr)
polyg <- data.frame(x = c(0, 15, 15, 0),
                    y = c(0, 0, 15, 15))

# Here is your point
point_inside <- matrix(c(5, 5), ncol = 2)
secr::pointsInPolygon(point_inside, polyg)

# Here is an arbitrary point outside
point_outside <- matrix(c(16, 5), ncol = 2)
secr::pointsInPolygon(point_outside, polyg)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up replacing it y `mgcv::in.out()`, also much faster.